# Method to make intro article break the returned when there's a space

Tags: php, function

i want to make a method for article intro which would break the returned text on a space, comma, period, semicolon, question mark, or exclamation point. i was stuck in to this code:

```
  function getIntro($count = 200) {
        return substr(strip_tags($this->content), 0, $count) . '...';
    }
```

please tell me how can i do that with my function?

Comment: what are the inputs and expected outputs? I am not too sure if I understand the question

Comment: the input is in $this->article, i'm expecting it returned part of my article before it reach $count when there's space, comma, period, semicolon or other.

Comment: in this function it's stop at word 200 using ... so it will cut some word.

Comment: We have no idea what $this->article is. I meant in terms of actual input values and expected outputs. input : 4 output: 5

Comment: @taesu Hes jsut trying to excerpt an article. I think its safe to assume that `$this->content` is the body of the article with HTML markup. What he wants is to get an excerpt of that article at a set string length rounded up/down to the nearest "word" (sans HTML tags).

Comment: let say i have article like this  : "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution", i wish my function will make intro stop at word normal, rather than stop at word distribu and then cut it.

Comment: this->content is my article, which is a sentences or plain text. that's all.

Comment: I see, let me see if i can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function splitAtBlank($string, $tryToSplitAt){
    $string = substr($string, 0, $tryToSplitAt);

    $i = strlen($string);
    $i--;
    while($string[$i] != " " && $i > 0){
        $i--;
    }

    return substr($string, 0, $i);
}
```

Then you can use it simply :

```
echo splitAtBlank("Your string", 8);
```

For your purpose :

```
function getIntro($count = 200) {
    $string = substr(strip_tags($this->content), 0, $count);

    $i = strlen($string);
    $i--;
    while($string[$i] != " " && $i > 0){
        $i--;
    }

    return substr($string, 0, $i) . '...';
}
```

And another version to handle multiple separators :

```
function getIntro($count = 200){
    $chars = array(' ', '.', ',', '!', '?');
    $string = substr(strip_tags($this->content), 0, $count);
    $i = strlen($string) - 1;
    while(!in_array($string[$i], $chars) && $i > 0){
        $i--;
    }
    return substr($string, 0, $i) . '...';
}
```

If you have some HTML tags in you article, you should use `strip_tags()` before spliting it.
If you need to handle tags open/closed states comment this post.

Comment: i think it work, but i have to adapt your function with my function

Comment: I add the code to match with your initial function ;)

Comment: don't you should change $tryToSplitAt with $count? . well this code is work, i just still wait is it any other code that more short.. maybe :D

Comment: if i want it stop at comma too should i use like this: $string[$i] != " " || "," || "."?

Comment: last example handle every chars you need

Comment: wait, need time to test

Comment: i just notice when i use your second method i didn't get error, but when i use the third i see an Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 200, do you know what's wrong?

Comment: an you fix your code to work like the second function?

Comment: i was about to do that ( add -1) but you already change it. thanks now it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the nearest space, comma, period, semicolon, question mark, or exclamation point before position 200, you have to look for all of them and get the biggest portion of text available.

So if your text is:

> $text='"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
>   by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout? The
>   point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
>   distribution", i wish my function will make intro stop at word normal,
>   rather than stop at word distribu and then cut,it';

```
   //cut the string at 200

$cut_text=substr($text,0,200);

   //look for all these characters.
   //strripos returns the position of the last occurrance of the character

$needles=array(' ','.',',','?','!',';');
foreach($needles as $needle){
    $pos[]=strripos($cut_text,$needle);
    }

   //sort the array to get the biggest 'position'. The biggest is $pos[0]

rsort($pos);

  //look if there is found a match, if not: just take the 200 characters

if(empty($pos[0])){$result=$cut_text;}
else{
    $result=substr($cut_text,0,$pos[0]);
    }
echo $result;
```

In the example it cuts the text right after

> more-or-less normal

Comment: didn't work with other symbol, just work with space.

Comment: @Kyo. You're right. Corrected the answer: `arsort` had to be `rsort`. And `$key` wasn't needed at all. Now it should work

Comment: sorry it still not work with comma. @Spoke44 is the correct one, but his last function causing Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 200